# WCF InstanceContextMode.PerCall, shared data between calls

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services, singleton, shared

How can I have shared data between instances of a WCF service, when using InstanceContextMode.PerCall, I need to have a shared list that instances will write and read to?

**EDIT**

Using @usr idea I created a singleton class that has a Queue where the WCF service will register its messages, and in the singleton class I have a running thread that will consume messages from the queue, producer/consumer problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain your shared data in a different class than the service class and have your service class be stateless. The stateless service can obtain the singleton instance and use it.

Here's a sketch:

```
class MySingleton {
 //You can use any lazy initialization logic you like
 //I just used a static initializer as an example
 public static readonly MySingleton Instance = new ...();

 //Move all static data into this class
 //Use it from anywhere you like
}

class MyWcfService {
 //This WCF service has no state
 //Any instancing mode will do
 public void SomeServiceMethod() {
  MySingleton.Instance.DoSomething();
 }
}
```

---

This has nothing to do with the question: Stateful web-services and web-apps are to be avoided. You must assume that the application is killed at any time (for example a power failure, crash, bug, ...). Also, you need a high availability solution which usually involves instantiating the application multiple times.

Comment: Just one more thing, I will host my WCF service in a Windows Service, maybe the is a solution to have that data at Windows Service level and not in WCF service, if it does make sense.

Comment: Yeah, that also makes sense. You just need to provide the service class a reference to the shared data somehow. A static variable is an easy way to do that.

Comment: Yes this could solve my issue, but I could not find a way to send that data to WCF.